# NASM Hello World Segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

So yeah, I am tinkering with assembly level programming...

Here is what I have so far.

```
global _start

section .text
_start:

    mov eax, 4      ; write
    mov ebx, 1      ; stdout
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msg.len
    int 0x80        ; system call


    mov eax, 1      ; exit
    mov ebx, 0      ; exit code
    int 0x80        ; system call

section .data

    msg: db "Hello world!", 10  ; Defines the string "Hello world!\n"
    .len equ $-msg
```

How does the statement `.len equ $-msg` work? I understand this is the length of the string. I also know that equ is like `#define` in C. So this variable does not exist in memory, it is put in place by the assembler. (nasm)

What does the $ symbol do, and is that a subtraction occurring afterwards?

<s>My output causes a segfault, I am hoping I will be able to fix this myself when I understand the `.len equ $-msg` syntax.</s>  I have fixed the fault, but still don't understand the $ notion.

**EDIT**  <s>Segfault caused by this being a malformed program.</s>  Fixed

Comment: Could you add your fix for the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` represents the address of the current line. So the following:

```
.len  equ  $-msg
```

Means the current address minus the address of `msg`. That gives the length of the data stored between `msg` and `.len` (since the address of `.len` is represented by `$`). Thus, the symbol `.len` represents (equated to) that length value.

Comment: So the length must always be computed immediately after defining the string, on the next line?

Comment: Correct. Note that your tag says `64bit`. What you've got there is 32-bit code.

Comment: @EdwardBird yes, in asm things are quite literal. If that were on a different line, with any instructions in between, then `$` would be a different value (represent a different memory address) and then `$-msg` would not be the length of `msg`.

Comment: @FrankKotler How did you tell it was 32 bit code? What would the differences be, or was it simply because I used the 32 bit register? (And therefore intel-syntax using assemblers will infer the value to be 64 bit from the instruction operands, which in this case would be a 32 bit register, implying 32 bit value for .len ?

Comment: You used `int 0x80`, used 32-bit registers for parameters, used 32-bit system call numbers. 64-bit code uses `syscall`, different (64-bit) registers for parameters, and different system call numbers. Presumably, you used "-f elf64" to assemble this, which makes it 64-bit code (try `push eax` - it won't work in 64-bit code!). The old 32-bit `int 0x80` interface still works (always? I dunno), so it's sort of a "mongrel" - I shouldn't have said "32-bit code" (unless you assembled it with "-f elf32"... or "-f elf" is an alias). 32-bit code has never heard of `rax` of course!